# AC Evaporator coil died and replaced with a bigger unit

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I hope I can ask this question here. I think my repair dude just pulled one over on me and would like to get some help if possible.

My evaporator coil went out, Carrier model CNPHP6024ALAAAAA.

I believe the correct replacement is CVPMA6024XMC but the installer put in CVPMA6124XMC. the 6214 unit is a bigger physical unit and some other technical stuff I don't understand, COIL STATIC PRESSURE DROP?? per the spec sheet.

What kind of problems is this going to cause me? Seems like it is taking much longer to cool down.

My unit is 4 ton: CA16NA04800G

Specifications: https://www.shareddocs.com/hvac/docs/1009/Public/08/PDSCVPMA-01.pdf

Dimensions sheet: https://i.imgur.com/L2VFy2m.png

Comment: The only difference is it's 61 now instead of 60..... 60~62 is 5 ton. It's listed in the manual, so.... either go with that or call Carrier. Swapping a coil is the last part I'd cheat someone on. I'd be like, aw man it's the coil? We ain't gonna make any money on this job.... Up-charge you on a condenser though? Hell yeah!

Answer (score 1):

First off, the strange item I first noticed was that all three evaporator coils you listed are rated for a 5 ton unit and you have a 4 ton so the specs will be different to start off with. The coil your installer put in is higher than the old one and if it fit into the area, then there's no problem, he just had to remove some of the ductwork for the larger unit or lower the entire handler. The unit that was replaced is listed as one to be used in cramped areas because of the smaller size. The coil in the new, larger unit is probably a little different than the old one which would account for the lower static pressure drop. That number is only useful when compairing pressure drops over time for air flow problems.

Bottom line: You won't see any difference in the new one from the old one. Like I said before though, all three coils mentioned are rated for 5 ton and you have a 4 ton. So maybe the coils have never been as cold as they should have been since they were larger. It might be their practice to beef up the coil. The installer could have adjusted the speed of the blower because of this.

Comment: @Ruskes Yes there is.  You're thinking of the condenser unit. There are ducts on the furnace or evaporator connecting to the house ductwork

Comment: Adjusted the blower speed down, i.e., decrease the blower speed? What is the purpose of having the suction line be cold where it enters the condensing unit?

Comment: @JimStewart  I was thinking adjusting it lower to make up for the larger coil that wouldn't be as cold once he realized the coil was a 5 ton and condenser was a 4 ton... just a guess.  Would give air more time to get cold.